# Exception Connecting:QuietException : Server is online mode!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

I am building a minecraft server, using PaperMC (a fork of spigot) and BungeeCord.
I have turned my spigot.yml to offline mode, and turned BungeeCord on. When I connect to the server it gives the error:

```
Exception Connecting:QuietException : Server is online mode!
```

server.properties:

```
#Minecraft server properties
#Sat Feb 29 19:19:35 UTC 2020
broadcast-rcon-to-ops=true
view-distance=10
max-build-height=256
server-ip=
level-seed=
rcon.port=25575
gamemode=survival
server-port=25560
allow-nether=true
enable-command-block=false
enable-rcon=false
enable-query=false
op-permission-level=4
prevent-proxy-connections=false
generator-settings=
resource-pack=
level-name=world
rcon.password=
player-idle-timeout=0
motd=NovaRex.org's Officaial Minecraft Server
query.port=25566
force-gamemode=false
debug=false
hardcore=false
white-list=false
broadcast-console-to-ops=true
pvp=true
spawn-npcs=true
generate-structures=true
spawn-animals=true
snooper-enabled=true
difficulty=easy
function-permission-level=2
network-compression-threshold=256
level-type=default
spawn-monsters=true
max-tick-time=60000
enforce-whitelist=false
use-native-transport=true
max-players=20
resource-pack-sha1=
spawn-protection=16
online-mode=false
allow-flight=false
max-world-size=29999984
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `server.properties` instead of your `spigot.yml`; the `server.properties` file takes precedence.

Comment: my server.properties is set to offline mode also. I added it in my post.